# Using IoT Edge communication in a Dockerized React app

Tags: reactjs, docker, create-react-app, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I have a React application (Create-React-App based), containerized into a Docker container, which is then deployed onto an IoT-Edge device. The React app is (trying to) using the '`azure-iot-device`' and '`azure-iot-device-mqtt'` libs so it would be able to communicate with IoT Hub (and, with other backend NodeJS applications, deployed as Docker-containers on the device).

The problem seems to be that '`azure-iot-device`' internally relies on environment variables, such as '`IOTEDGE_WORKLOADURI`' and [other environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-iot-device/moduleclient?view=azure-node-latest#fromenvironment-any-).

As far as I understand, there is no way to set environment varables on a React app in runtime (note - we need those env vars to be available from `process.env`, and not on a global configuration file or `window`. Reason is above - the library internally relies on those values, directly from `process.env.XXX` to establish communication). Trying to provide those variables in build time is a bad idea and not scalable either (we would need connection strings, etc.)

What is the best way to achieve communication then, from a React app on an IoT-Edge device? Is it impossible at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

So basically the problem is

First of all, it must be clear that there is no such thing as environment variables inside the browser environment. Whichever solution we use nowadays is nothing but a fake abstraction.

But, then you might ask, what about .env files and REACT_APP prefixed environment variables which come straight from documentation? Even inside the source code, these are used as process.env just like we use environment variables inside Node.js.

In reality, the object process does not exist inside the browser environment, it’s Node-specific. CRA by default doesn’t do server-side rendering. It can’t inject environment variables during content serving (like Next.js does). During transpiling, Webpack process replaces all occurrences of process.env with a string value that was given. This means it can only be configured during build time.

So there are some work arounds, [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-implement-runtime-environment-variables-with-create-react-app-docker-and-nginx-7f9d42a91d70/)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. What you are saying makes sense and mostly known to me. I am not specifically asking how to set environment variables in React in runtime - I gave up on that idea. My question is: given this limitation of environment variables not being accessible to a React app, is there another way to communicate between this app and IoT Hub ?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a React application (Create-React-App based), containerized into a Docker container, which is then deployed onto an IoT-Edge device.

'classic' - builded app served by nginx ?

> The React app is (trying to) using the 'azure-iot-device' and 'azure-iot-device-mqtt' libs ...

... and communication with hub works sometimes, not always? Stops without active browser window ? ... weird idea

> ... so it would be able to communicate with IoT Hub (and, with other backend NodeJS applications, deployed as Docker-containers on the device).

You probably need another (or extend existing) NodeJS backend app using these libs (always running bi-directional communication with azure iot hub) and a "channel" (f.e. sockets/graphql subscriptions) for communication with [served] react app (nginx/express) - man in the middle (like proxy).

By using sockets (for realtime react app updates) you're abstracting/hidding all backend details (including credentials - more secure), f.e. you can change protocol without react app change.

Of course react app can 'ask' backend for some vars (or invoke events/actions) like in standard client-server communication - by requests (fetch - server url/routes, REST-like API...).

Comment: React app is served by http-server in this case, but eventually it looks like what you suggested was the way to go; Use sockets over docker network interface to communicate with a backend up seems to be the only solution in this case (Bi-directional communication is needed). Thanks